# What is a Type Literal in Java?

Tags: java, literals, abstract-syntax-tree

There is an ASTNode subclass called [`TypeLiteral`.](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/ArrayInitializer.html)

The description of this type of code says that it looks like

`( Type | void ) . class`

I don't believe I have ever seen anything like this.

Can anyone provide an example of a `TypeLiteral`, and perhaps additionally of it being used in a Java program?

Answer (score 2):

There is a class called [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) that represents the class of an object. It contains various useful methods for introspection on that class and objects of that class. One way to get a class object is to use the `Object` method `getClass()`. But if you want to refer to a `Class` by name of its class, you use a class literal.

Some examples:

```
class Foo {
  void method(Object b) {
    if(b.getClass() == Foo.class) {
      Foo f = Foo.class.cast(b);
    }
    Foo.class.getResourceAsStream(...);
    Foo.class.getMethod("method", Object.class);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain? What does `.class` do? Also, why is it called a `TypeLiteral`? Where is the `Type` and what is `Literal` about it?